# Comparing a List of tuples in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

Ok, I'm extremely new to Haskell as in I started learning this morning, and have been tasked with taking 2 lists of tuples [("s",1)..] and returning true if they have all the same elements otherwise return false.
So far I'm thinking of taking the first element from list one and comparing it to all the elements in list 2 and do that for all the elements and then return true or false. I don't know how to keep track of all the booleans, its easy for if there is a false

```
|head list1 =/ elementList2 = False
```

but i'm just confusing my self, so far i have, I have already defined List

```
listCheck :: List->List -> Bool
listCheck (h1:t1) (h1:t1)
    | h1 == [] = True
    | fst (head h1) /= fst (head h2) = False
    | snd (head h1) /= snd (head h2) = False
    | otherwise = listCheck (t1) (t2)
```

Any suggestions?
The lists can be in any order, so [("a",1),("b",1)] and [("b",1),("a",1)] are equal. the order of the lists can't be changed.

Comment: My idea is that you go through the list checkign

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'returning true if they compare the same elements otherwise return false'? Do you mean that it should return true if they contain exactly the same elements, regardless of order? Or the same elements in the same order? Or if there is at least one element in common between the lists? Please be precise.

Comment: It sounds like you want `listCheck = (==)` or `listCheck = Data.List.isPrefixOf`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is reasonable to take the head of the list and create an equality function using it. The use `any` or `all` from the [List library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) to compare with the tail.

As this is a college exercise I guess you don't want the answer given to you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
listCheck l1 l2 = sort l1 == sort l2
```

will work fine if list elements are totally ordered, which they will be in the usual case of Strings, numbers etc (and naturally tuples of such elements).

If your elements don't have an ordering things get a lot more difficult, but I don't think you'll encounter that situation often.

Answer (score 0):

The way I always recommend newcomers approach this problem is this:

1. Look for ways to solve the problem by using standard library functions.
2. When you've succeeded at that, write your own version of every library functions you used.

In this case, your description of what you're thinking can be finessed into a #1-style solution.  Let's quote it:

> So far I'm thinking of taking the first element from list one and comparing it to all the elements in list 2 and do that for all the elements and then return true or false.

Here, instead of thinking of doing that just with the first element, picture doing the same thing to *all* the elements as one step to the solution.  There's a standard function that captures this pattern:

```
-- The `map` function applies the function given as the first argument
-- to all of the elements of the second argument.  The result is a list
-- of all the individual results.
--
-- Example:
--
-- >>> map (+10) [1, 2, 3, 4]
-- [11, 12, 13, 14]
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So if you can write a function that tests for *one* value whether it exists in the second list, you can use `map` to apply that function to *all* elements of the first list:

```
step1 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
step1 xs ys = map checkOne xs
  where checkOne x = _fillInTheBlank
```

(The `_fillInTheBlank` bit is called a "hole"—you're supposed to actually write the correct code in there!)

The second step would be to check the `[Bool]` to see whether all of the elements are `True`.  You return `True` if they are, and `False` if at least one is false.  There is a standard function for that as well:

```
-- Returns `False` if any element of the list is `False`, `True` otherwise.
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

And now:

```
listCheck :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
listCheck xs ys = and (map checkOne xs)
  where checkOne x = _fillInTheBlank

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
-- Write your own version of `map`


and :: [Bool] -> Bool
-- Write your own version of `and`
```

Note what I've done: I've split the problem into smaller parts, each of which I can solve with functions like `map` and `and` that will be useful in many other cases.  That's what you should be shooting for.

Comment: You probably meant `and`, not `all`? Though `all pred` is of course favoured over `and . map pred`.

Comment: Is there a parenthesis mistake in `listCheck` in your last snippet?

Comment: @Bergi: oops, yeah, I did mean `and`.  I don't see any parenthesis mistakes though.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's the same thing. I had expected something like `all (… checkOne) xs` (with the closing parens shifted), but in that case the `map` is misplaced.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to compare the nth element of each list, you are quite close already. The only problem is that you are pattern-matching to pull the two lists apart into head/tail, and then acting as if you hadn't, calling `head` and `tail` again:

```
listCheck :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
listCheck xs ys
    | xs == [] = True
    | fst (head xs) /= fst (head ys) = False
    | snd (head xs) /= snd (head ys) = False
    | otherwise = listCheck (tail xs) (tail ys)
```

This is far from the most elegant way of doing things, but it is the closest I could find to what you seemed to be trying to write.

Comment: Don't use `head` and `tail` when you can do pattern matching. Partial functions should be avoided, especially by beginners.

Comment: …especially if this lures you into using them onto lists that could be empty.

Comment: As I said, this is not the best way to do things, but seemed the closest to the approach laid out in the question. If I were going to just reimplement this function from scratch it would be quite different: something like `listCheck = (and .) . zipWith (==)`, or `listCheck = (==)` if the short-circuiting behavior is not desired.